# Implement the recursive insert method of binary search tree in RUST

Tags: java, algorithm, rust, binary-search-tree

I'm learning Rust and trying to implement a simple binary search tree (actually it's rewriting the Java implementation below). Here is what I have done:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

// Node of this BST, the two generic types are key and value
struct Node<K:Ord, V> {
    key: K,
    value: V,
    left: Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>,
    number_of_nodes: i32,
}

impl<K: Ord, V> Node<K, V> {
    // Create a new node
    fn new(key: K, value: V, number_of_nodes: i32) -> Node<K, V>{
        Node {
            key,
            value,
            left: None,
            right: None,
            number_of_nodes,
        }
    }
}

struct BST<K: Ord ,V> {
    root: Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>,
}

impl<K: Ord, V> BST<K, V> {
    // Get the size of this BST
    fn size(&self) -> i32 {
        size(&self.root)
    }

    // Search for key. Update value if found, otherwise insert the new node
    fn put(&self, key: K, value: V) {
        self.root = put(&self.root, key, value)
    }
}

// Function for recursively get the size of a sub BST 
fn size<K: Ord, V>(node: &Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>) -> i32 {
    match node {
        Some(real_node) => real_node.number_of_nodes,
        None => 0,
    }
}

// Function for recursively put a new node to this BST
fn put<K: Ord, V>(node: &Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>, key: K, value: V) -> &Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>{
    match node {
        None => {
            let new_node = Some(Box::new(Node::new(key, value, 1)));
            return &new_node;
        },
        Some(real_node) => {
            match key.cmp(&real_node.key) {
                Ordering::Less => real_node.left = *put(&real_node.left, key, value),
                Ordering::Greater => real_node.right = *put(&real_node.right, key, value), 
                Ordering::Equal => real_node.value = value,
            }
            real_node.number_of_nodes = size(&real_node.right) + size(&real_node.left) + 1;
            node
        },
    }
}
```

But this code won't compile, at the line `self.root = put(&self.root, key, value)`, I get an error:

> mismatched types
> expected enum 'Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>'   found
> reference '&Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>'

I don't know how to fix that, I tried to change the `&self` parameter to `self`, or `self.root` to `*self.root`, but I got more errors. I'm so confused about the reference in Rust, all I wanna do is rewrite the following Java code in Rust.

```
public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
{
    private Node root;              //root of BST

    private class Node
    {
        private Key key;            // key
        private Value val;          // associated value
        private Node right, left;   // left and right subtrees
        private int N;              // number of nodes in subtree

        public Node(Key key, Value val, int N)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.val = val;
            this.N = N;
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of key-value pairs in this symbol table.
    public int size()
    {
        return size(root);
    }

    // Return number of key-value pairs in BST rooted at x
    private int size(Node x)
    {
        if (x == null) return 0;
        else return x.N;
    }

    public void put(Key key, Value val)
    {
        root = put(root, key, val);
    }

    private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val)
    {
        if (x == null) return new Node(key, val, 1);
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if (cmp < 0) x.left = put(x.left, key, val);
        else if (cmp > 0) x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
        else x.val = val;
        x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
        return x;
    }
}
```

It's dead simple in `Java` because I don't need to handle the reference. So here is my problems:

1. How could I fix that mismatched error?
2. What is the proper return type of that recursive function `put`, the
   `&Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>` or `Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>`? What's the difference?
3. Am I on the right way to rewrite this `Java` code? The rust-analyzer only reports this mismatched error but I don't know if it will work as I expect. And honestly I don't
   fully understand what am i doing when I handle the reference in rust
   especially when it's a reference of a struct or enum

It's hard to learn Rust because I don't have much experience in system programming language, I appreciated your guys help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to take a mutable reference to the node:

```rust
impl<K: Ord, V> BST<K, V> {
    // ...

    fn put(&mut self, key: K, value: V) {
        put(&mut self.root, key, value)
    }
}

fn put<K: Ord, V>(node: &mut Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>, key: K, value: V) {
    match node {
        None => {
            *node = Some(Box::new(Node::new(key, value, 1)));
        }
        Some(real_node) => {
            if key < real_node.key {
                put(&mut real_node.left, key, value);
            } else {
                put(&mut real_node.right, key, value);
            }

            real_node.number_of_nodes = size(&real_node.right) + size(&real_node.left) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could take the node by value and return the modified node:

```rust
impl<K: Ord, V> BST<K, V> {
    // ...

    pub fn put(&mut self, key: K, value: V) {
        self.root = put(self.root.take(), key, value);
    }
}

fn put<K: Ord, V>(node: Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>, key: K, value: V) -> Option<Box<Node<K, V>>> {
    match node {
        None => Some(Box::new(Node::new(key, value, 1))),
        Some(mut real_node) => {
            if key < real_node.key {
                real_node.left = put(real_node.left, key, value);
            } else {
                real_node.right = put(real_node.right, key, value);
            }

            real_node.number_of_nodes = size(&real_node.right) + size(&real_node.left) + 1;
            Some(real_node)
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest reading the [ownership and references chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) of the Rust book if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks mate. The mutable reference method is so much clear. But the number of nodes won't increment if we insert a new key that already existed. When we put a existed node we update the value of that key. I implement the get methods and tested it couple times, the size of this BST should be fine

Comment: In your second code block the first parameter of the recursive method `put` is `Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>`. And the `self.root` is also an `Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>`. But we can't directly put `self.root` into that function. That's why I use reference instead of let that function take the ownership. And it's kinda weird because we can do this thing in other data types like `String`, but in this case we need to use the `take()` function. That's the thing that confused me I think, anyway thanks man

Answer (score 0):

```
fn put<K: Ord, V>(node: &mut Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>, key: K, value: V) {
    // match value. look how bst work. 
    // left branch values less, right brannch values are greater
    match value {
        // in this case we are looking at the righ branch
        if value>self.value{
            // if none, just set node.right
            // i think instead of 1, it should be self.number_of_nodes+1
            None => self.right=Some(Box::new(Node::new(key, value, 1))),
            // since we are inserting we need ref to the node
            // this will recursively add
            Some(ref mut real_node) => real_node.put(value)   
        // this case value<=self.value so we are at the left branch  
        } else{
            None=>self.left=Some(Box::new(Node::new(key, value, 1))),
            Some(ref mut real_node)=>real_node.put(value)
        }    
    }
}
```